# Geopy: OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

Tags: python, geocoding, geopy

I'm using `Geopy` library to convert a list of English name locations to latitude and longitude. However, halfway through the execution, the program raised an error: `OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable`. I was wondering if there's related to my code or it's simply the network error?

My code:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('/*****.csv')

for cell in df['Offices']:
    cell = pinyin.get(cell, format="strip", delimiter='')
    place = str(cell)
    geolocator = Nominatim(timeout=3)
    location = geolocator.geocode(place)
    print(location)
    if location:
        print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
print('Converting finished.')
```

The full exception as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1392, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 936, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 724, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

Comment: Generally, [OSError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#OSError) raises for system-related errors returned from system functions. So, yes, I would check the network first. Try reaching `nominatim.openstreetmap.org` from the machine you run the code on.